# jquery datepicker(monthpicker) - initialize Month & year dropdown onclick

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I initialize jquery's monthPicker as shown below code.

I would to set Month/year downdown based on the existing value in monthpicker input box during on click. i.e if the value set is "May 2015", then month picker should show the calendar with dropdown initialized with May/2015. My code below is not doing this.

Thanks in advance!.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {


        $(".monthPicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'M yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            showAnim: '',
            duration: '',
            currentText: 'Present',
            beforeShow: function(input) {
                 setTimeout(function () {
                    $(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-current").hide(); 
                    $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("hide-calendar");
                    $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass('MonthDatePicker');
                    $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass('HideTodayButton');
                    var thisCalendar = $(this);
                    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
                 },1);
                }
            }
        });

        $(".monthPicker").focus(function () {
            var thisCalendar = $(this);
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();

        });

        function onClickMonthPicker(){

    var currentDateOfAnalysis = $(".monthPicker").val();
     if(!$.isUndefinedOrEmptyObject(currentDateOfAnalysis)){

     var currentDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd M yy", "1 "+currentDateOfAnalysis);
     $(".monthPicker").datepicker('option','defaultDate', currentDate);
    }

 }

 <input name="monPickField" id="monPickField" class="monthPicker" onClick="onClickMonthPicker();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a call to onClickMonthPicker in the beforeShow method like this...

```
beforeShow: function (input) {
        onClickMonthPicker();
        .... }
```

I notice you have an extra } and also this line is also causing an issue if(!$.isUndefinedOrEmptyObject(currentDateOfAnalysis))
You can try to something as simple as a check for empty string to debug your code. There are different ways to check so I let you tinker with that and decide for yourself. I pick the easy route in this case (see code below).

For the shake of completion, I polished your code with an onClose method as well.

Here is the complete code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.monthPicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showAnim: '',
        duration: '',
        currentText: 'Present',
        beforeShow: function (input) {
            onClickMonthPicker();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(input).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-current").hide();
                $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("hide-calendar");
                $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass('MonthDatePicker');
                $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass('HideTodayButton');
                var thisCalendar = $(this);
                $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
            }, 1);
        },

        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }

    });

    $(".monthPicker").focus(function () {
        var thisCalendar = $(this);
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    });

});

function onClickMonthPicker() {
    var currentDateOfAnalysis = $(".monthPicker").val();
    if (currentDateOfAnalysis != '') {
        var currentDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd M yy", "1 " + currentDateOfAnalysis);
        $(".monthPicker").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', currentDate);
    }
}
```

No changes to your html. Hope this helps.